# How to get the object from PostgreSQL DB of the logged in user with a querySet in Django?

Tags: python, django

I would like to only fetch the row from the database where the pk equals to the pk of the logged in user. In my case the pk is an `uuid` called `DID`.

**What I tried:**

```
def getAccountInfo(request, *args, **kwargs):
    account_information = serializers.serialize('json', AccountInformation.objects.filter(pk=request.user.DID))
    return HttpResponse(account_information)
```

```
def getAccountInfo(request, *args, **kwargs):
    account_information = serializers.serialize('json', AccountInformation.objects.filter(pk=request.user.pk))
    return HttpResponse(account_information)
```

with both attempts returning empty objects.

**This is a snippet of the DB:**

[image]

**Edit:**
This works just fine, I used a wrong account while testing...

```
def getAccountInfo(request, *args, **kwargs):
    account_information = serializers.serialize('json', AccountInformation.objects.filter(pk=request.user.DID))
    return HttpResponse(account_information)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming you have a User table (maybe the default?) and an AccountInformation table which is what you showed above as having accountNumber being an integer.

I think your problem is that accountNumber is supposed to be a foreign key to User table, so you should really have:
`AccountInformation.objects.filter(accountNumber=request.user.pk)`

Otherwise, you should NEVER have a UUID as a pk IF you are going to be searching/filtering through the pk.

Comment: closing the question since everything works just fine...I was just logged in with the wrong account. But I will consider your input nevertheless. Thank you!